# How to return varchar string instead of null with rollup?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

When I run this query:

```
select
    First_Name,
    sum(a) a,
    sum(b) b,
    sum(c) c
from someTable
group by First_Name with rollup
```

the first column `First_Name` and the last row (total row) shows a NULL (since it can't be summed), I want to show a custom string value instead of null.  I know I can use `isnull` or a `case` here, but I want only the rolled up row to be affected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN GROUPING_ID(First_Name) = 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE First_Name END,
        SUM(a),
        SUM(b),
        SUM(c)
FROM    data
GROUP BY
        First_Name WITH ROLLUP
```

Answer (score 1):

`CASE WHEN GROUPING(First_Name) = 1 THEN 'FOO' ELSE First_Name END AS First_Name`